# I can't seem to override a function using template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm trying to alter the comment links in my Drupal output, and I think I have found the function I want to influence, which is `function comment_node_view($node, $view_mode)`.

It is in the Comment module. The problem is I can't seem to effect it, when I try to override it by putting it in my Template.php file and add my theme_ to the function name? In my template.php it looks like this now:

```
function themename_comment_node_view($node, $view_mode)
```

if I take off the themename_ it causes an error saying I can't redeclare it.  I can copy the comment module and edit it directly but I thought this was how I theme something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal themes can only implement theme functions (which include template preprocess and process functions) or [alter hooks](http://drupal.org/node/254940#theme_alter).

[comment_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7) is a hook, but it's not an alter hook (differently the hook name would end with "_alter").

Why cannot themes implement `hook_node_view()`?

Because `hook_node_view()` is invoked in [comment_build_comment()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_build_content/7) using the following code:

```
  // Allow modules to make their own additions to the comment.
  module_invoke_all('comment_view', $comment, $view_mode, $langcode);
  module_invoke_all('entity_view', $comment, 'comment', $view_mode, $langcode);
```

As it is also highlighted from the comment, [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) invokes the hooks implemented in modules, not themes.

If you want to change how a comment is rendered, from a theme, you should create the [comment.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.tpl.php/7) template file for your theme.

Comment: I'm afriad dont follow your advice. its most likely not your understanding but mine. I'm trying to alter the function, but if I cannot add my own version of this function then do I only have the option of editing the module directly?

Comment: `comment_node_view()` is not a theme function because the function name would start with `theme_`, and it is not a hook alter function, or the function name would end with `_alter`. Therefore, you cannot implement `themename_node_view()` in a theme. `themename_comment_node_view()` for Drupal is not a special function, and it doesn't automatically call it; it's not even a Drupal hook.

Comment: There is no need to edit a Drupal core module, which is never suggested to be done. You just need to add the "comment.tpl.php" template file in your theme, if you just need to alter how a comment is rendered when the selected theme is the one you wrote.

Answer (score -2):

The name spacing is 'hook_node_view' so you need to replace 'comment' (the name spacing used by the comment module) with your theme name:

```
function mytheme_node_view($node, $view_node)
```

Hooks:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7

hook_node_view:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that really makes sense. but unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work for me. I implemented this, but it still ignores my new version. I am sucessfully overriding another function which is "function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables)"
so I assume all is well with my template.php file... any idea?